# Can you play without doing any companion quest?

Tags: pathfinder-kingmaker

I would like to play *Pathfinder Kingmaker* without doing any companion quests (*Harrim*, *Tristan*, and so on...).

If I am able to refuse *Amiri* wish to kill "Gouttière" (the name of the boar in the french edition) and don't see her quest in my journal, *Harrim* companion quest, however, is in my journal even if I tell him that I do not wish to visit his dwarf fortress.

Is my game doomed to fail if I refuse to do the quests of my companions ? Will they all leave and me be without advisors ?